# Match whitespace created by Chrome devtools source view?

Tags: regex, coldfusion, google-chrome-devtools

```
<span style='mso-tab-count:1'>         </span>
<span style='mso-tab-count:1'>         </span>
```

The bottom line above is from a "View Source Code" page and the top line is from the Chrome Developer Tools Source view. The RegEx below matches the bottom tags, which contain a series of spaces, but not the top tags, which enclose just empty whitespace. See this on the Regex Tester at https://regex101.com/r/P9dUP9/2

```
(<span style='mso-tab-count:1'>)\s{2,}(<\/span>)
```

How could I make the Regex also match the top line, and how can I tell the difference between the two kinds of whitespace on the screen without copying and pasting both of them into a text editor?

Comment: I am converting 2500 characters of tabular data on a website to a comma-separated list. The table also contains about 2500 spaces. But the source code was generated by a word processor which inflates the file size of the table to 50,000 characters, 4000 of which are whitespace and 16,000 are XML which seemingly has nothing to do with the table. I use the regex to clear out the bloat and CSS and leave just the data, since I do not know how to use java or jsoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's a non-printable control character. My hex editor tells me it's `\x20`, but that's not captured for me. Your best bet would be using an exclusion such as:

`(<span style='mso-tab-count:1'>)[^<]{2,}(<\/span>)`

or

`(<span style='mso-tab-count:1'>)\W{2,}(<\/span>)`

Comment: This is just what I needed. Th*nks!